# Natural logarithm implementation when only logarithm base 2 is available

Tags: c, logging, cuda, ptx

I am trying to implement the natural logarithm with PTX. PTX natively only provides `lg2.approx.f32` which implements the logarithm to base 2. Thus, applying simple maths one can get the natural logarithm by just multiplying the logarithm to base 2 with the logarithm to base 2 of Euler's number e:

`log_e(a) = log_2(a) / lg_2(e)`

To a first approximation `1/lg_2(e)` is `0.693147`. So, I would just multiply with this number.

I had `nvcc` compile the `log` function (from CUDA C) into PTX (please find the output below). I can see multiplying with the numerical constant at the end. But there is a lot more stuff going on. Is this important? Can someone explain why there is so much overhead?

```
    .entry _Z6kernelPfS_ (
        .param .u64 __cudaparm__Z6kernelPfS__out,
        .param .u64 __cudaparm__Z6kernelPfS__in)
    {
    .reg .u32 %r<13>;
    .reg .u64 %rd<4>;
    .reg .f32 %f<48>;
    .reg .pred %p<4>;
    .loc    14  3   0
$LDWbegin__Z6kernelPfS_:
    .loc    14  5   0
    ld.param.u64    %rd1, [__cudaparm__Z6kernelPfS__in];
    ld.global.f32   %f1, [%rd1+0];
    .loc    16  9365    0
    mov.f32     %f2, 0f00000000;        // 0
    set.gt.u32.f32  %r1, %f1, %f2;
    neg.s32     %r2, %r1;
    mov.f32     %f3, 0f7f800000;        // ((1.0F)/(0.0F))
    set.lt.u32.f32  %r3, %f1, %f3;
    neg.s32     %r4, %r3;
    and.b32     %r5, %r2, %r4;
    mov.u32     %r6, 0;
    setp.eq.s32     %p1, %r5, %r6;
    @%p1 bra    $Lt_0_2306;
    .loc    16  8512    0
    mov.b32     %r7, %f1;
    and.b32     %r8, %r7, -2139095041;
    or.b32  %r9, %r8, 1065353216;
    mov.b32     %f4, %r9;
    mov.f32     %f5, %f4;
    .loc    16  8513    0
    shr.u32     %r10, %r7, 23;
    sub.u32     %r11, %r10, 127;
    mov.f32     %f6, 0f3fb504f3;        // 1.41421
    setp.gt.f32     %p2, %f4, %f6;
    @!%p2 bra   $Lt_0_2562;
    .loc    16  8515    0
    mov.f32     %f7, 0f3f000000;        // 0.5
    mul.f32     %f5, %f4, %f7;
    .loc    16  8516    0
    add.s32     %r11, %r11, 1;
$Lt_0_2562:
    .loc    16  8429    0
    mov.f32     %f8, 0fbf800000;        // -1
    add.f32     %f9, %f5, %f8;
    mov.f32     %f10, 0f3f800000;       // 1
    add.f32     %f11, %f5, %f10;
    neg.f32     %f12, %f9;
    div.approx.f32  %f13, %f9, %f11;
    mul.rn.f32  %f14, %f12, %f13;
    add.rn.f32  %f15, %f9, %f14;
    mul.f32     %f16, %f15, %f15;
    mov.f32     %f17, 0f3b2063c3;       // 0.00244735
    mov.f32     %f18, %f17;
    mov.f32     %f19, %f16;
    mov.f32     %f20, 0f3c4c4be0;       // 0.0124693
    mov.f32     %f21, %f20;
    mad.f32 %f22, %f18, %f19, %f21;
    mov.f32     %f23, %f22;
    mov.f32     %f24, %f23;
    mov.f32     %f25, %f16;
    mov.f32     %f26, 0f3daaab50;       // 0.0833346
    mov.f32     %f27, %f26;
    mad.f32 %f28, %f24, %f25, %f27;
    mov.f32     %f29, %f28;
    mul.f32     %f30, %f16, %f29;
    mov.f32     %f31, %f30;
    mov.f32     %f32, %f15;
    mov.f32     %f33, %f14;
    mad.f32 %f34, %f31, %f32, %f33;
    mov.f32     %f35, %f34;
    cvt.rn.f32.s32  %f36, %r11;
    mov.f32     %f37, %f36;
    mov.f32     %f38, 0f3f317218;       // 0.693147
    mov.f32     %f39, %f38;
    add.f32     %f40, %f9, %f35;
    mov.f32     %f41, %f40;
    mad.f32 %f42, %f37, %f39, %f41;
    mov.f32     %f43, %f42;
    .loc    16  8523    0
    mov.f32     %f44, %f43;
    bra.uni     $Lt_0_2050;
$Lt_0_2306:
    .loc    16  8526    0
    lg2.approx.f32  %f45, %f1;
    mov.f32     %f46, 0f3f317218;       // 0.693147
    mul.f32     %f44, %f45, %f46;
$Lt_0_2050:
    .loc    14  5   0
    ld.param.u64    %rd2, [__cudaparm__Z6kernelPfS__out];
    st.global.f32   [%rd2+0], %f44;
    .loc    14  6   0
    exit;
$LDWend__Z6kernelPfS_:
    } // _Z6kernelPfS_
```

*** EDIT ***

Just to be complete. Here the CUDA C kernel that I compiled into the above PTX:

```
__global__ void kernel(float *out, float *in)
{
  *out = log( *in );
}
```

Comment: You can check out the C source code for logf() in math_functions.h. The log2 built into the GPU hardware has large relative error close to 1.0, so a pure software approximation is used instead of the hardware to achieve a small ulp error across the entire function domain. If you want just the hardware log2 plus the back-multiply, use __logf() instead of logf().

Comment: Good idea. I just tried `logf`. Unfortunately no change in the PTX. Seems they use the approximation anyway. Do you see in what case the code branches to "hardware lg2 and back-multiply". To me its not comprehensive.

Comment: __logf() with two leading underscores is the "fast math" version that maps straight to the hardware approximation. See source in file device_functions.h. The regular logf() function uses __logf() only to handle exceptional cases as can easily be seen by looking at the source code in math_functions.h. Both files are readily available on any machine that has CUDA installed, since the CUDA standard math library is just a collection of header files at this point.

Comment: Yes, `__logf()` produces only the hardware + multiply version of it. That is the code after label `Lt_0_2306`. Back to my question: There is one branch command in the approximation code to that label. Would you say this branch is taken if Pade approximation breaks down? As a failsafe version.

Comment: From the source:

if ((a > CUDART_ZERO_F) && (a < CUDART_INF_F)) {
[...] 
} else {
  /* handle special cases */
  return __logf(a);
} The approximation used for the non-exceptional path is a minimax approximation. I don't recall using Pade approximations anywhere in the CUDA math library.

Comment: Oh! Now, I see. The approximation routine is implemented in CUDA C and its not the `nvcc` that has it built in. Should take a look there. Many thanks!

Comment: The funny part seems to be that the original routine uses log2 approximation to return +-Inf/+-NaN for <=0 or extreme cases and for other values it uses a polynomial approximation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function appears to calculate log2 of a floating point number by setting the exponent part to 1 (effectively scaling to range  `1<x<2`) and then calculating a 3rd degree polynomial approximation. **EDIT**: appears to be rational [Pade approximation](http://www.nezumi.demon.co.uk/consult/logx.htm), as Taylor series for log(1+x) converges badly. Thus calculating the reciprocal.

Probably no more than a handful of instruction could be shaved off. (the code is multiplying with 0.5 instead of subtracting from exponent and such trivial stuff. e.g. testing argument x<=0.)

Comment: Single-precision floating-point computation on NVIDIA's GPUs is often no more expensive than integer computation. Analysis of the efficiency of the code has to occur at the SASS level, which is what executes on the hardware. PTX is just portable intermediate code and not fully optimized. Since this question prompted me to look at the source code for logf(), I used the opportunity to streamline the code a bit more :-)

Comment: Aki, thanks a lot! I was looking for this for months.